# excel vb loop/concatenate - what am Idoing wrong

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to make all my btn invisible. They are named:

```
btnHere1

btnHere2

btnHere3

btnHere4
```

`For i = 1 To 4
        ["btnHere" & i].Visible = False
    Next`

Answer (score 0):

```
for i = 1 to 4 : me.controls("btnHere" & i).visible = false : next i
```

If run from outside of form, replace Me by a form object reference.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to loop through all controls in your form:

```
Dim ctrl As Control

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls

    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CommandButton" Then
        ctrl.Visible = False
    End If

Next ctrl
```

This technique means that you don't need to reference your buttons by name as in your code example.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have buttons on the spreadsheet itself as opposed to a form they are actually shapes, although you can still name them btnSomethingOrOther.

If you wanted to make these invisible then just iterate through the shapes on sheet...

```
For Each control In ActiveSheet.Shapes
   If Mid(control.Name, 1, 3) = "btn" Then
       control.Visible = False
   End If
Next
```

However If you do have an actual form you are using then the first answer will do the trick fine as well.